# Pass generic type in c++ method as parameter

Tags: c++, generics

I am trying to implement a c++ method and want to pass a generic parameter in it. I only want to assign that parameter to an object's property. Here is an example:

```
class Myclass {
public:
    unsigned long long var1;
    unsigned short var2;
    signed short var3; 
}
```

Now I have a global object of Myclass in SomeOtherClass and a method says:

```
void SomeOtherClass::updateMyClassValue(int paramType, <Generic> value) {
     switch(paramType) {
         case1:
          objMyClass.var1 = value;
         case2:
          objMyClass.var2 = value;
         case3:
          objMyClass.var3 = value;
     }
}
```

How to pass such  type, because if I use a fixed type e.g `unsigned long long` as parameter type, I won't be able to assign it to var2 & var3. I also don't want to loose data, e.g signed data may have -ve value.

Please help me to overcome this situation, I have no experience working in c++. I am not sure if I can achieve this using templete<> in c++, if yes than how?

Thanks

Comment: this is where templates come into play. Just posting some code wont help you mate. Take a look at this tutorial since templates is a huge and big deal in c++: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part

Comment: Do you need all three variables?

Comment: Also the example above is a bad example (bad design) since you need to check the type which renders templates useless and you could just as well put 1 functions inside MyClass with correct data type.

Comment: If by `var1` you don't mean the member variable with name `var1` but the first member variable with some other name there is no way to do it in c++.

Answer (score 4):

Pass the parameter by pointer:

```
void SomeOtherClass::updateMyClassValue(int paramType, void* pValue) {
 switch(paramType) {
     case1:
      objMyClass.var1 = *(unsigned long long*)pValue;
     case2:
      objMyClass.var2 = *(unsigned short)pValue;
     case3:
      objMyClass.var3 = *(signed short)pValue;
 }
```

This is of course not type-safe and you can get into a lot of trouble when you accidentally specify the wrong paramType. If you use a member template function instead, you can let the compiler do some checking for you, for example:

```
template<type T>
void SomeOtherClass::updateMyClassValue<short int>(T value) {
    objMyClass.var2 = value;
}
```

More elegant and type-safe.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is by function overloading:

```
template <class T>
void updateMyClassValue(T value) {
    //assert, or log message, or nothing, if not needed you can remove this function
}

void updateMyClassValue(unsigned long long value) {
    var1 = value;
}

void updateMyClassValue(unsigned short value) {
    var2 = value;
}

void updateMyClassValue(signed short value) {
    var3 = value;
}
```

Another approach is to have a type like [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/any/s02.html).

Comment: it is better not to have the template overload, and to have a compilation error

Comment: Function should no thrown error when you can control it during compilation process. Better to keep the function unimplemented (as I had revised your answer). That will result in link error, if anything wrong passed. But it seems that you reverted back.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to overload your function for the types for which you want the update. This will be decided compile time and hence you can save few cycles and code lines for `switch/case`. For unwanted types, you may have a `private` function.

Below is one way to *avoid repetitive code*:

```
#define UPDATE(VAR) VAR; \  
public: void updateMyClassValue (const decltype(VAR)& value) { VAR = value; }

class Myclass {
public:
    unsigned long long UPDATE(var1);
    unsigned short UPDATE(var2);
    signed short UPDATE(var3); 

private: template<typename T> void updateMyClassValue (T);
};
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/ibu3tx) which also includes the error scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it relates to your problem, since you're in need of basic types. But i've noticed no one have mentioned the following:

I. Inheritance mechanism:

```
class BaseType;

class Var1 : public BaseType
{};
class Var2 : public BaseType
{};
class Var3 : public BaseType
{};

class Myclass
{
public:
    Var1 m_var1;
    Var2 m_var2;
    Var3 m_var3;
};

void SomeOtherClass::updateMyClassValue(int paramType, BaseType value) {
     switch(paramType) {
         case1:
          objMyClass.m_var1 = value;
         case2:
          objMyClass.m_var2 = value;
         case3:
          objMyClass.m_var3 = value;
     }
}
```

Of course, there's no type check, etc.,
but it is a valid option, being checked on ***compile time***.

II. Callback mechanism:

Again, I think it might be too complax for your problem, but you can also pass a callback function for setting a specific member value, and the value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it using templates. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Myclass {
public:
    unsigned long long var1;
    unsigned short var2;
    signed short var3;
};

class SomeOtherClass
{

public:

    Myclass objMyClass;

    template <typename T>
    void updateMyClassValue(int paramType, T value);


};




template <typename T>
void SomeOtherClass::updateMyClassValue(int paramType, T value) {

    switch(paramType) {
        case 1:
            objMyClass.var1 = value;
        case 2:
            objMyClass.var2 = value;
        case 3:
            objMyClass.var3 = value;
    }
}

int main() {


    SomeOtherClass soc;


    unsigned long long var1 = 11;
    unsigned short var2     = 22;
    signed short var3       = 33;

    soc.updateMyClassValue(1, var1);
    soc.updateMyClassValue(2, var2);
    soc.updateMyClassValue(3, var3);

    cout << soc.objMyClass.var1 << endl;
    cout << soc.objMyClass.var2 << endl;
    cout << soc.objMyClass.var3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
11
22
33
```

Comment: Here, unfortunately, you have compatible type, if you add `std::string`, you will have compiler error.

Comment: @Marcin thanks for this, but having problem when calling the same with objective c. Objective c in not supporting function overload and that's why I am not able to call it from objc. To do that I need to call this template method from my c++ class so compiler can create a copy with the given type. Do you have any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do what you want, as the other answers suggest: template method, pointers, overloaded method, generic types like `boost::any`.

But before choosing one of them, look at your problem from a design perspective. You have a class with three member variables with different types. What do they *mean*, what do they *represent*? Are they different representations of the exact same attribute of the class or are they completely different attributes of that class (think of the class from an OO perspective, not as a simple C++ syntactic construct)?

**Case 1** - different ways to represent the same value

In this case think about storing the value in a single form in the class and convert it to the other forms of representation on demand.

E.g.: you're designing a `Temperature` class that can hold the temperature in either Celsius or Fahrenheit degrees. Instead of having to members to store the temperature in each of the two formats, have just one and convert it to the other format when needed.

```
class Temperature
{
public:
    void setCelsius(double degrees)
    {
        celsiusTemperature = degrees;
    }

    void setFahrenheit(double degrees)
    {
        celsiusTemperature = (degrees - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0;
    }

    double getCelsius() const
    {
        return celsiusTemperature;
    }

    double getFahrenheit() const
    {
        return celsiusTemperature * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32;
    }

private:
    double celsiusTemperature;
}
```

**Case 2** - different values/attributes of the class

If the variables hold different attributes of the class and mean different things, then have different methods to set them, instead of a generic method to set each and every one of them. A variable should be named and typed according to it's purpose and to the meaning of the value it stores. A setter for a variable should be named and typed according to the same principles.

E.g.

```
class Person
{
public:
private:
    string name;
    int age;
    double height;
}
```

In this case what would be more obvious, to have a generic method

```
void setPersonAttribute(int attributeType, T value);
```

or have a method for each attribute

```
void setName(string name);
void setAge(int age);
void setHeight(double height);
```